# Listing all directories recursively within the zipfile without extracting in python

Tags: python, file, directory, file-structure, python-zipfile

In Python we can get the list of all files within a zipfile without extracting the zip file using the below code.

```
import zipfile
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilepath, 'r')
    for file in zip_ref.namelist():
        print file
```

Similarly is there a way to fetch the list of all directories and sub directories within the zipfile without extracting the zipfile?

Comment: I don't believe `zipfile` has that capability. you could theoretically use `zlib` and try to parse the "[central directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Structure)" yourself, but unless these files are prohibitively large and you have a lot of them, I wouldn't go to all that trouble.  I'll keep looking for a more reasonable soln. though

Comment: Tried [`ZipFile.infolist`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist)?

Comment: @metatoaster a quick test I did indicates that this even spits out files in a predictable order (depth first alphabetical) confirm? deny? thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by without "extracting the zip file"?  Those methods provide a list and in order to produce the list the manifest have to be extracted first...

Answer (score 1):

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilepath, 'r') as myzip:
   print(myzip.printdir())
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your help.

```
import zipfile

subdirs_list = []
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Download/sample.zip', 'r')
for dir in zip_ref.namelist():
    if dir.endswith('/'):
        subdirs_list.append(os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(dir)))

print subdirs_list
```

With the above code, I would be able to get a list of all directories and subdirectoies within my zipfile without extracting the sample.zip.